# Accessing dictionary value element when there are multiple values

Tags: c#

```
foreach (var file in d.GetFiles("*.csv"))
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(file.FullName))
            {
                List<string> columns = new List<string>();
                string colLine = File.ReadLines(file.FullName).First(); // gets the first line from file.
                columns = colLine.Split(',').ToList();
                reader.ReadLine(); // skip first line

                dynamic x = new ExpandoObject();
                var eoa = (IDictionary<string, object>)x;

                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    var line = reader.ReadLine();
                    var values = line.Split(',');
                    for (int idx = 0; idx < values.Length; idx++)
                    {
                        if (values[idx] == "\"\"")
                        {
                            values[idx] = "[BLANK]";
                        }
                    }

                    int i = 0;
                    foreach (var value in values)
                    {
                        List<string> val = new List<string>();
                        val.Add(value);

                        if (!eoa.ContainsKey(columns.ElementAt(i)))
                        {
                            eoa.Add(columns.ElementAt(i), val);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            List<string> overwrite = new List<string>();
                            var curr = eoa[columns.ElementAt(i)];
                            foreach (var v in (dynamic)curr)
                            {
                                overwrite.Add(v);
                            }
                            overwrite.Add(value);
                            eoa[columns.ElementAt(i)] = overwrite;

                        }
                        i++;
                    }
                }
                using (StreamWriter outFile = new StreamWriter(path + @"\output.txt"))
                {
                    foreach (var entry in eoa)
                    {
                        var test = entry.Value as List;
                        outFile.Write("{0}:{1} ", entry.Key, entry.Value);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

[image]

I'm currently unable to get the value of an index belonging to the test variable. I try doing test[0] but get the error "Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'. I am curious what other ways I can attempt so that these list elements can be accessed which belong to the Value of my dictionary.

Comment: Post all the code relevant to your question.

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What does "Without changing the parameters of the IDictionary" mean? You can always do `var test = entry.Value as List;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your value seems to be of type `object`, and as the error suggests you can't directly apply indexing to it. You have to cast it to a `List<string>` to use test[0].